# Normalize values in a column to obtain overheads

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
      Target=rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=8),
      Prov=rep(letters[1:4],each=2),
      B=rep("5MB"),
      S=rep("1MB"),
      BUF=rep("8kB"),
      M=rep(c('g','p')),
      Thr.mean=1:24)
```

whose column `Thr.mean` I would like to normalize by the values where `Target=='C'` (I don't mind attaching a new column).

To clarify, I would like to end up with:

```
Thr.mean <- c(1/17,2/18,3/19,4/20,5/21,6/22,7/23,8/24,9/17,10/18,11/19,12/20,13/21,14/22,15/23,16/24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Now, it may happen that there are rows in this data frame, where `Target!='C'`, and they have values in `S` or `B` that are not present in rows where `Target=='C'`, and for these I would also like to calculate the overhead. The most important column for matching is `M`, then `BUF`, `B`, and `S`.

Any ideas how to do it? I could write several loops and ifs, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: what do you mean by normalize in this context ? Also the Thr.mean series you want has less number of rows than the original data frame. Pardon me but this is causing a little confusion.

Comment: fixed the `Thr.mean` series, thanks for pointing that out. By normalizing I mean that I have certain set of measurements that I would like to treat as the norm (`Target=='C'` in the example), and normalize the observations (`Thr.mean` column) in other measurements/experiments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity,

the way how I solved my problem is by using `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, Thr.Norm.C := .SD[Target=='C', Thr.mean], by = 'B,BUF,Prov']
DT[, over.thr := Thr.Norm.C/Thr.mean]
```